# Where the class "section" is defined?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I just downloaded a bootstrap template. The body of `index.html` consists of several sections:

```
<section id="promo" class="promo section offset-header has-pattern"> 
...
</section>

<section id="features" class="features section">
...
</section>

<section id="how" class="how section has-pattern">
...
</section>
```

In its `styles.css`, I could find, for example,

```
.features {
  padding: 80px 0;
}
.features .icon {
  ...
}
.features .icon:hover {
  ...
}
.features .icon:hover .fa {
  ...
}
```

However, I could NOT find anything about `section`. Does anyone know where the style of `features section` (and `promo section offset-header has-pattern`, `how section has-pattern`) is normally defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `section` class in Bootstrap is just `display: block;`

Below is the Bootstrap code where `section` is defined. This is defined on about `line 26` in the [bootstrap CSS file](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css).

```
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Then, how should I interpret the style of `features section`?

Comment: @SoftTimur Basically a top padding of 80px (defined in your code) and display of block (defined in Bootstrap). Basically meaning the content inside the object will start 80 pixels from the top. That object will then take up the entire width of it's parent even if the content inside doesn't span the entire width. Let me know if you have any other questions or if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I see... so the selector `class="features section"` means `features` **AND** `section` as explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_class_more2).

Comment: Yes. When you separate classes by a space in HTML it will inherit CSS attributes from both. Remember if you overwrite certain CSS style attributes in a future class those will overwrite the earlier ones. For example if in features you set `display` to something else in your CSS code it won't change anything since `section` comes after `features`. Unless you switch the order. If that makes sense.